# Reading commits in reverse using GitPython

Tags: python, gitpython

Is there a way to iterate commits in reverse using the GitPython lib, that is, from the oldest one to the newest, in a similar manner to:

```
>>> from git import Repo
>>> repo = Repo('/path/to/repo')
>>> for commit in reversed(repo.iter_commits()):
...     print commit
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument to reversed() must be a sequence
```

Without having to include everything in memory first, as my case is dealing with lots of commits (e.g. the linux kernel)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=iter_commits#git.repo.base.Repo.iter_commits) it appears that `iter_commits` is passing its kwargs to `git-rev-list`. Looking at its [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) reveals that it accepts a `--reverse` flag, so one can only guess that `repo.iter_commits(reverse=True)` would work.

Answer (score -1):

The main problem here is that in reverse you need to pass the sequence. but iter_commits return an iterator.
so you can do
`commitList = list(repo.iter_commits())`

and then use the reverselogic on the commitList

Comment: OP stated `Without having to include everything in memory first`. You solution does just that

Comment: oh I am sorry .